# Login with Vimeo using C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a project and in this I have to implement login using Vimeo account. Furthermore I get application key and other information by registering my application on Vimeo. But on the Vimeo site there is no help how to implement the login functionality, and I am new to it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[Vimeo uses OAuth](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/authentication), so you should be able to find an OAuth library for .NET and start working pretty quickly. [This blog post](http://www.robgreen.me/post/Getting-Started-With-The-Vimeo-API-in-C.aspx) looks like a good starting point and covers authentication as well as searching.

Comment: yes i am using OAuth and i am able to request the the token and after when i click on Authorization Requested on vimeo site and after the vimeo redirect me to on my site then i am requesting for token(http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token) then i am getting the error (The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized)

Comment: Did you pass your API key? Check out the section _Authenticating a User_ at http://www.vimeo.com/api/docs/oauth.